# mysql pattern select based on values

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I cant think up some good solution. My database structure is:

```
id   name
----------
 9   beer
10   beer {cold}
11   beer {hot}
12   juice
13   juice {orange}
14   juice {green}
15   juice {black}
```

I need select so possible output to have:
- one row of main product 
- and all same products containing any text between characters {%} will be an alternatives of main product.

I need this output: (2 rows with alternatives -- but no 7 rows)

```
array(
    array(
       id => 9,
       name => beer,
       alternatives => array (
          array(
             id => 10,
             name => cold
          ),
          array(
             id => 11,
             name => hot
          )
       )
    ),
    array(
       id => 12,
       name => juice
       alternatives => array (
          array(
             id => 13,
             name => orange
          ),
          array(
             id => 14,
             name => green
          ),
          array(
             id => 15,
             name => black
          )
       )
    )
);
```

Do you think, is this possible with ONE Query?

Comment: you should redesign your table and put the hot/cold attribute into a separate field. `(id, name, extra_info)`. that'll make it MUCH easier to group by a particular product, and eliminate any chance of a mis-grouping, e.g. `broccoli` v.s. `broccolini`

Comment: ok, i will use addiational field ... but is possible to avoid this alternatives in count results? ex. no 7 rows, but only 2?

Comment: `select id, name from yourtable group by name`.

Comment: @Marc B: that query isn't going to get you 2 rows which include the attributes.  There is no way to compact things into the structure drozdo is looking for, but I would argue that it is closer to the structure he wants using your suggestion.  Some fancy function stuff could get really close, but I don't see the issue with getting 7 rows, and post processing them in PHP.

Comment: We don't have enough information to understand the right structure.  For example:  is it important that you have an ID for each item/attribute combination?  Let's say this was an inventory system.  It might be important that you have a separate ID for "juice - orange" and "juice - green" so that you can relate inventory and sales tables to those specific  combinations.  There are several ways to design things, and the business rules will drive which design you would use.